# Cisco Callmanager JTAPI events flow

Tags: jtapi, cucm

I wonder is there some cisco document for JTAPI events flow for some basic calls? (Cisco IP - Cisco IP, 3d-party IP - Cisco IP, Analog - Cisco IP)? 
Searched through Cisco JTAPI developers guide, but found flows only for transfer/agent calling

Answer (score 0):

It can be different based on a number of factors, including:

- The version of CUCM you are running
- The version of JTAPI you are using
- The type (SCCP/SIP) and model of phone you are using to make/receive a call
- The level of CTI access the application user is provisioned

I recommend you download the JTAPI test tool that corresponds to the CUCM version you are using and see what events you get. That's what I've had to do. ;)

Here are the published versions:

- [10.0(1) JTAPI Test Tool for Unified CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/7a529a66-fb2c-4f57-8822-c1b047be10b4) 
  11 May 2014: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 10.0(1)
- [9.0(1) JTAPI Test Tool for Unified CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/d2e5d765-7337-4537-a91e-cc1e59089193) 
  14 Feb 2013: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 9.0(1)
- [8.6(1) JTAPI Test Tool for Unified CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/e90390e4-70c2-40e3-9997-0ee4b2661391) 
  8 Jul 2011: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 8.6(1).
- [8.5(1) JTAPI Test Tool for Unified CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/3f48e912-b621-411c-80f1-83bb829b179b) 
  12 Jan 2011: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 8.5(1).
- [8.0(1) JTAPI Test Tool for Unified CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/8c1f90b3-42ef-4893-acbf-1f6bcb535537)
  16 Feb 2010: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 8.0(1).
- [7.1(3) Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for Unifed CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/75fcdc70-0092-4f88-910a-eb262972209b)
  25 Sep 2009: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 7.1(3).
- [7.1(2) Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for Unifed CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/cb4ea80f-a7fc-4ce2-a7fa-e82fcb70f363) 
  26 May 2009: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 7.1(2).
- [7.0(1) Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for Unifed CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/2be9f29b-642b-436a-88dc-26dd1921bbcf) 
  26 May 2009: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 7.0(1).
- [6.0(1) Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for Unifed CM.zip](https://developer.cisco.com/fileMedia/download/e7254fb8-c157-4814-808c-a5b5db062eec) 
  26 May 2009: Cisco JTAPI Test Tool for use with Cisco Unified Communications Manager 6.0(1).